# How is a class-C amplifier useful?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, power-amplifier

As I understand, class-C amplifier can only generate signal of constant frequency and amplitude. So the question is, how can it be useful and what are its applications?

[image]

Comment: Amplitude doesn't have to be constant, and frequency can vary within the passband of that LC filter. So, AM radio and FM radio transmitters.

Comment: @BrianDrummond How can amplitude and frequency vary?

Comment: They both come from the input signal so of course they can vary.

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Class C.  The output amplitude is largely determined by the supply voltage.  But -- still good for FM, or on-off keying, or PSK.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I guess I don't fully understand how it works then. I was assuming that the output is driven by the tank circuit which has constant frequency.

Comment: The output is driven by the transistor -- the tank circuit is passive, it can only *be* driven.  Typically, the tank circuit has some bandwidth over which it works; as long as the signal that's being amplified is within the tank circuit's bandwidth, the amplifier will work.

Answer (score 2):

Narrow band RF applications are where the class C amplifeir is useful. FM, PM,FSK, and PSK schemes don't rely on amplitude linearity so the good efficiency  and simplicity of class C is an advantage. AM can be implemented by modulating the power supply voltage, which is also simple.

Comment: @Rodion Degtyar  Classic AM modulator for C-class amps adds AC (for. example an audio signal) to the power supply DC. The secondary winding of a transformer is in series with the DC supply. The method has a drawback: As much AC power is needed from the transformer as there's needed DC power to generate the AM carrier. I the power of the AM carrier is say 5W in a walkie talkie, a 5W audio amp is needed to feed the modulation transformer.

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand, class-C amplifier can only generate signal of constant frequency and amplitude.

It's not that restricted.

A class-C amplifier can only generate a signal at a single frequency, but that frequency can vary within the bandwidth of the output filter.  So, for example, if you drive it with a frequency- or phase-modulated signal, its output will be similarly modulated.

A properly-driven class-C amplifier will generate a signal at an amplitude that is determined by its voltage supply.  So you can amplitude modulate a class-C amplifier.

Note that it is much easier to do this cleanly with a *tube* class C amplifier -- I'm not sure if this is done with *transistor* class C amplifiers.

I honestly don't know if a brand new high-power (50kW or more) FM or AM radio broadcast transmitter would have tubes or transistors in the finals -- in 1980, the answer would have been a resounding "tubes!".  This would be an interesting topic to chase down if you have a few hours to spend on the Internet.

Comment: Note that many of the latest airborne radars, such as the F-22, F-35, and the latest version of what's in the F-16, operate their final output power amplifier, or PA, in class-C mode, for efficiency reasons.